Manually remove recipient(-s) from a scheduled mailing - no "Create" API3/API4 action for the MailingRecipients entity
Is it possible to manually remove recipient(-s) from scheduled mailing?
It seems there is no "Create" action for the MailingRecipients entity in both API3/API4 (and the "update/remove/replace" are deprecated).
Related issues:

CiviMail and Smart Groups: when does CiviCRM identify the actual list of email recipients?
Change group after a mailing is scheduled results in mailing still being send to the original members
Scheduled mail and reminders to groups


Are you capable of working with sql? civicrm_mailing_recipients has columns
| id
| mailing_id
| contact_id
| email_id
| phone_id

@nielo Thank you for your input, the original question is about API tools though.
